# Does a sorcerer have to learn spells from somewhere, or do they learn them by leveling up?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, sorcerer

I'm new to DnD 3.5 and I'm wondering: how does a sorcerer learn new spells?

We have a party member who insists sorcerers have to learn spells from spell books or from other sources.

On the other hand the Player's Handbook says on the page 179:

> For instance, when Hennet the sorcerer becomes 2nd level, he
>   gains an additional 0-level spell. He can pick that spell from the 0-
>   level spells on the sorcerer and wizard spell list, or he might have
>   learned an unusual spell from an arcane scroll or spellbook.

Which I'm interpreting as Hennet the sorcerer getting the 0-level spell instantly without a need to learn it from anywhere as long as the spell is from the sorcerer and wizard spell list.

tl;dr:
Do sorcerers just gain "slots" when they level up and have to learn the spell from somewhere, or do they get the "slot" AND the spell?

Comment: Do you mean mechanically or lore-wise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### He learns primarily from leveling up, but not only that way.

> A sorcerer’s selection of spells is extremely limited. A sorcerer begins play knowing four 0-level spells and two 1st-level spells of your choice. At each new sorcerer level, he gains one or more new spells, as indicated on Table: Sorcerer Spells Known. [...] ***These new spells can be common spells chosen from the sorcerer/wizard spell list, or they can be unusual spells that the sorcerer has gained some understanding of by study***. The sorcerer can’t use this method of spell acquisition to learn spells at a faster rate, however.

As I emphasized on this quote, the sorcerer can learn any spell from the sorcerer/wizard spell list. When learning these spells, he learns them spontaneously when he concentrates on his spells the first time after leveling up. Most times, the spell will just pop-up on the sorcerer's mind this way.

The other method, the study, is to allow sorcerer players to research and learn spells developed by themselves or others; spells that aren't on the book. Basically, originals or spells from a source that the DM doesn't use but allowed a PC/NPC to research that specific spell.

If your spell is on the sorcerer/wizard spell list from a sourcebook that your DM allows and he didn't forbid that specific spell, you just level up and learn the spell with no further effort from your character.